# Keil UV5.23/24/25 crashes on a 2nd start of debug session on Emulator

Tags: arm, keil

I have encountered a problem with uVision and Hitex emulator (Tanto2) on a Win10 laptop (fresh install).
My initial setup was UV5.23, I updated to 5.24 and made tentative with 5.25 on Keil's request.
I have a dedicated SDK release for UV5.23, I switched to a new one for UV5.24.

Firmware emulator was reflashed when I was using SDK for UV5.23, and updated when moving to UV5.24

What I can do: 
- start UV5, open my project, 
- start a debug session on the emulator, load my project, make the first run and stop debug session.

Whatever the release I use, the problem appears when I want to start a second debug session on the emulator. Once I click on the Start Debug, UV5 crashes with this message: 
"uVision IDE has stopped working 
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will ..."

I need to relaunch UV5 to run a new debug session.

The setup using Keil 5.23 and its dedicated SDK release was OK till the end of March.

Since the end of March, the Windows updates that have appeared are: KB4088776, KB4093110, KB4093112, KB890830, KB4099989.
I tried uninstalling KB4099989, but there was no change, the problem is still present.

Is there a link with these updates? 
If someone encounters the same problem and was able to solve it, I hear you :-)

The same problem appears on the laptop of my colleague whereas it is working fine before the last Windows update.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem with uVision 5 on Windows 10, the difference being that it allows me to run as many times as I like, but crashes the first time I try to open the debugger.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I ask the support of the emulator (now part of Infineon) and they delivered a new release of SDK. This was working well until last update of Win10 end of July ...

Comment: Hi, @JCV, thank you for the information. We use Keil uVision 5 for course-work and what did the trick for us was to change some settings under the Debug tab of the Target options. But this is just a workaround and not a solution

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the below issue. If there is a crash in application during dll unload, windows adds an entry in registry to ignore a future unload dll request. So if the application tries to load the dll again within the same session, then the application crashes.

As a workaround goto the below location in registry,

My Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

and delete the unload registry path. Everytime if there is a new crash then the dll will be added back which needs to be removed.

Answer (score -1):

[work around]
I also get crashes when entering debugger session, however I noticed that it occurs only if I click the debugger icon and then leave the pointer over that icon.  I have never had it crash if I click and *immediately move the pointer away*.